# Start/pause pygame via tkinter button in the same window

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame, embed

For a school project, a friend and I do a game in pygame. The pygame window is embedded in a tkinter frame. As soon as you open the application the game starts immediately. Now we want to start and pause the game with buttons from tkinter. I'm glad for any help, thanks.

```
import pygame, random, sys
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame.key import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import os
```

Creates a tkinter frame

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Borderflip")
embed = tk.Frame(root, width = 500, height = 500) #Erzeugt einen 
eingebetteten Rahmen für das Pygame-Fenster
embed.grid(columnspan = (600), rowspan = 500) 
embed.pack(side = LEFT) #Fenster nach rechts
buttonwin = tk.Frame(root, width = 75, height = 500)
buttonwin.pack(side = LEFT)
```

Here are the Buttons the
play and pause button is without a function

```
def play_button():

play_button = Button(root,  padx=8, width=18, pady=8, bd=8, font=("Arial", 
26), text="Play", command=play_button)
play_button.pack()

pause_button = Button(root,  padx=8, width=18, pady=8, bd=8, font=("Arial", 
26), text="Pause", command=root.quit)
pause_button.pack()

quit_button = Button(root, padx=8, width=18, pady=8, bd=8, font=("Arial", 
26), text="Quit", command=root.destroy)
quit_button.pack()
```

Code for integration of pygame in tkinter

```
os.environ['SDL_WINDOWID'] = str(embed.winfo_id())
os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER'] = 'windib'
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
screen.fill(pygame.Color(255,255,255))
pygame.display.init()
pygame.display.update()
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()
```

Code for the pygame

```
x = 500 # Breite und Höhe Fenster in Pixel
y = 500

sbreite = 100 # Breite und Höhe Schläger
shöhe = 15

sx = 200 # Definition 
sy = 450

bx = int(x/2)
by = int(y/2)

brad = 15

speed = 0

bxspeed = 1
byspeed = -2

leben = 10

def sblock():
    global speed
    if sx <= 0 or sx >= x-sbreite:
        speed = 0

def ballbewegung():
    global bx,by
    bx += bxspeed
    by += byspeed


def reset():
    global byspeed,bxspeed,leben,bx,by,sx,sy,speed
    sx = 200
    sy = 450

    bx = int(x/2)
    by = int(y/2)

speed = 0

bxspeed = random.randint(-2,2)
if bxspeed == 0:
    bxspeed = 1
byspeed = random.randint(-2,2)
if byspeed == 0:
    byspeed = 2
screen.fill((0,0,0))
pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255,255,0), (bx,by), brad, 0)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,40,0), (sx,sy,sbreite,shöhe), 0)
pygame.display.flip()
pygame.time.wait(1000)
root.update()

def ballblock():
    global byspeed, bxspeed, leben
    if by-brad <= 0:
        byspeed *= -1
    if bx-brad <= 0:
        bxspeed *= -1
    if bx+brad >= x:
        bxspeed *= -1
    if by >= 435 and by <= 440:
        if bx >= sx-15 and bx <= sx + sbreite + 15:
            byspeed *= -1
        else:
            leben -= 1
            reset()
    root.update()

def sbewegung():
    global sx
    sx += speed

while leben > 0:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                speed = -2
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                speed = 2
screen.fill((0,0,0))
sbewegung()
sblock()
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,40,0), (sx,sy,sbreite,shöhe), 0)

ballbewegung()
ballblock()
pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255,255,0), (bx,by), brad, 0)

pygame.display.flip()
pygame.time.wait(5)

print ("haha verloren")

while True:
    pygame.display.update()
    root.update()
```

Comment: Read [pygame.org/wiki/gui](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/gui) and [pygame-vs-tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668116/pygame-vs-tkinter)

Answer (score 1):

Tkinter + Pygame don't work well together sadly, usually due to conflicts between their graphics libraries and how one program sleeps when the other is active.

I would personally recommend removing tkinter from your project and building a `button` class through `pygame.sprite.Sprite()`, which can then be used in the same way a tkinter button would. You can read the documentation on that [Here.](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite)